# Set values programmatically to a Formik form from jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs, formik

I have an hybrid project with ReactJS and jQuery. I've created forms using Formik and updated their values from jQuery.

The problem is that Formik don't detect the values when they are setted programmatically from jQuery and when I submit the form the fields are empty.

I've tried to trigger from jQuery events like focusin, focusout, change but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a ref to your Formik component. In v1 it supported `ref` prop but in v2.0.0-2.1.1 they decided to remove it, i don’t know what was the reason but it’s back in v2.1.2 as `innerRef`. Use that ref in your jQuery code and update all the values through that reference of formik.
This part of react’s documentation is also useful.
https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: Welcome, If the answer was helpful then you can upvote it.